# Ant + GWT compiling two related projects

Tags: gwt, ant, compilation

I have a problem with using Ant to compile a GWT project which is split into two parts. First project which is GWT project- client side of a web app and the second project included in build path which is a data model for hibernate. When I'm runing a build.xml I'm geting errors that I forget to inherit some modules. Where should I include my second project? in javac? project.classpath? libs?
I'm using standard build.xml example from GWT showcase:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<project name="Showcase" default="build" basedir=".">
<!-- Arguments to gwtc and devmode targets -->
<property name="gwt.args" value="" />

<!-- Configure path to GWT SDK -->
<property name="gwt.sdk" location="../.." />

<path id="project.class.path">
<pathelement location="war/WEB-INF/classes"/>
<pathelement location="${gwt.sdk}/gwt-user.jar"/>
<fileset dir="${gwt.sdk}" includes="gwt-dev*.jar"/>
<!-- Add any additional non-server libs (such as JUnit) -->
<fileset dir="war/WEB-INF/lib" includes="**/*.jar"/>
</path>

<target name="libs" description="Copy libs to WEB-INF/lib">
<mkdir dir="war/WEB-INF/lib" />
<copy todir="war/WEB-INF/lib" file="${gwt.sdk}/gwt-servlet.jar" />
<copy todir="war/WEB-INF/lib" file="${gwt.sdk}/gwt-servlet-deps.jar" />
<!-- Add any additional server libs that need to be copied -->
</target>

<target name="javac" depends="libs" description="Compile java source to bytecode">
<mkdir dir="war/WEB-INF/classes"/>
<javac srcdir="src" includes="**" encoding="utf-8"
    destdir="war/WEB-INF/classes"
    source="1.5" target="1.5" nowarn="true"
    debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source">
  <classpath refid="project.class.path"/>
</javac>
<copy todir="war/WEB-INF/classes">
  <fileset dir="src" excludes="**/*.java"/>
</copy>
</target>

<target name="gwtc" depends="javac" description="GWT compile to JavaScript (production mode)">
<java failonerror="true" fork="true" classname="com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler">
</java>
</target>

<target name="devmode" depends="javac" description="Run development mode">
<java failonerror="true" fork="true" classname="com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode">
<classpath>
<pathelement location="src"/>
<path refid="project.class.path"/>
<pathelement location="../../validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar" />
<pathelement location="../../validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar" />
</classpath>
<jvmarg value="-Xmx256M"/>
<arg value="-startupUrl"/>
<arg value="Showcase.html"/>
<arg line="-war"/>
<arg value="war"/>
<!-- Additional arguments like -style PRETTY or -logLevel DEBUG -->
<arg line="${gwt.args}"/>
<arg value="com.google.gwt.sample.showcase.Showcase"/>
</java>
</target>

<target name="superdevmode" depends="javac" description="Run Super Dev Mode">
<java failonerror="true" fork="true" classname="com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer">
<classpath>
<pathelement location="src"/>
<pathelement location="../../gwt-codeserver.jar" />
<path refid="project.class.path"/>
<pathelement location="../../validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar" />
<pathelement location="../../validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar" />
</classpath>
<jvmarg value="-Xmx256M"/>
<arg value="com.google.gwt.sample.showcase.Showcase"/>
</java>
</target>

<target name="eclipse.generate" depends="libs" description="Generate eclipse project">
<java failonerror="true" fork="true" classname="com.google.gwt.user.tools.WebAppCreator">
<classpath>
<path refid="project.class.path"/>
</classpath>
<arg value="-XonlyEclipse"/>
<arg value="-ignore"/>
<arg value="com.google.gwt.sample.showcase.Showcase"/>
</java>
</target>

<target name="hosted" depends="devmode" description="Run development mode (NOTE: the 'hosted' target is deprecated)" />

<target name="build" depends="gwtc" description="Build this project" />

<target name="war" depends="build" description="Create a war file">
<zip destfile="Showcase.war" basedir="war"/>
</target>

<target name="clean" description="Cleans this project">
<delete dir="war/WEB-INF/classes" failonerror="false" />
<delete dir="war/showcase" failonerror="false" />
</target>

</project>
```

Comment: The usual surprise is that the GWT compiler wants to see source. It doesn't care about bytecode. You then need to make sure your module.gwt.xml is set correctly to make sure it is picking up all the source.

Comment: module.gwt.xml is set correctly because project compiles fine while using standard gwt plugin compiler

Comment: Are both sets of source available to the gwt compiler in the ant version then?

Comment: problem solved. It need to be included in gwtc target as a claspath